# NetSuite sublist

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am having a problem finding out an id of a sublist. I am using SuiteScript 1.0.  For instance, I need to list the components of an assembly item record, how do I find out the list id and the "type and field name to use in the nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue or nlapiGetCurrentLineItemValue methods. What I am looking for is how now and in the future when presented with a sublist, do I go about finding the ids of the objects needed. I have internal ids turned on but that does not help in the sublist view. What is the best way to get this information when I need it? thanks for any help you may give.

Answer (score 0):

You can use nlapiGetAllLineItems() to get an array of all the sublists. You may need to load the record first and do record.getAllLineItems()

Answer (score 0):

I have found the most useful method for figuring out internalids is to run `nlapiLoadRecord(..)` in your Browser Console and examine the resulting object. Another trick is the add `&xml=T` to the end of the URL of the record, which displays the record in XML format. NetSuite also documents most of the internalids in the [Records Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2016_2/script/record/account.html).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you use console in **Google Chrome.** Open the Specific Assembly Item Record page and Press **F12** and select console.After give following code

```
 nlapiLoadRecord('assemblyitem', 90088(id for specific record));
```

after show result in console. Select **linefields** and **Item**. Now it show the fields of sublist. If You have any doubt let me know.

Comment: It worked up to the point of the linefields but there is no "item" under linefields, I have tried all three and cannot seem to come up with the right info. I am on an Assembly Item record, it has a sub tab of components, in that list are inventory items. When I look att he object, I find a 'member' object that contains the items but I cannot seem to grab the item information.

Comment: If you need  line items. Try this in Console lineitems>component>Array[1]. or This not your solution tell me your issue clearly.

Comment: 'lineitems' comes back as not an object, but here is what I am trying to do. I have 'assemblyitem' records for the BOM which have items in a sublist. The tab is called components, but in Javascript, the lineitems object has an array called 'member' under which the items that I seek are stored, since I will need to edit these objects and persist those changes, I do need to have the correct methods to do that. Otherwise, I could just navigate with JS. Hopefully, someone knows what the problem is. Thanks for all your help.